# Best Event to initialize Fonts

Tags: vb.net, events, fonts

In a program (VB .NET), I give the users the ability to custom the fonts of the different controls (textbox, form, label, datagridview...)
For now, I use a routine on my base form(all others form inherits from it) which browse all control, and give them the font saveds in the settings (it CAN be different for every type of control). I use this routine because I can freeze the form (layout and drawing) during the redefinition of a font, to avoid the form blinking in resizing all control)

What is the right event to do that ? I currently use "OnControlCreated". But is it better to do it elsewhere ? like in New, in OnHandleCreated, OnLoad...

(hope my question is understandable, I'm French)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code on a program that changes the font and size of the text in every form / different per user. I use the OnLoad and eveything seems ok with doing that.

```
    Dim Different_Font As Font = New Font("Calibri", 10)
    Public Sub CheckFont(frm As Form)
        For Each ctl As Control In frm.Controls
            If ctl.HasChildren Then
                CheckFont_Children(ctl)
            End If
            Try
                ctl.Font = DifferentFont
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckFont_Children(parent As Control)
        For Each ctl In parent.Controls
            If ctl.HasChildren Then
                CheckFont_Children(ctl)
            End If
            Try
                ctl.font = DifferentFont
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

In the form load event call...

```
Private Sub Frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckFont(Me)
End Sub
```

This doesnt seem to resize any controls though, that might be a good or a bad thing for you.. Bon Chance! ;)

Comment: The resizes occurs when, for example, I change the size of the font (for a textbox for example). I have a lot of tablelayoutpanel with autosize, so the form "blinks" when I do that.

Comment: To stop the 'Blinking' you could use `SuspendLayout`[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=netframework-4.7.2) and `ResumeLayout`[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout?view=netframework-4.7.2), along with ensuring `DoubleBuffered = true`[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered?view=netframework-4.7.2)
(